# Java to MySQL connection

Tags: java, mysql

I am on EC2 linux instance, and I can't seem to get this java code to query the database, I am showing the error at the bottom of the code below. It indicates that it can't find the driver, knowing that I installed mysql-connector-java-5.1.12.jar manually, since it wasn't there when I installed Java. I am not sure how to check if the jar installed correctly though?

```
import java.sql.*;

 public class Java2MySql{
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
  String dbName = "myBlog";
  String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  String userName = "root";
  String password = "NoWay!";
  Connection conn = null;
  try {
       Class.forName(driver);
     }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
    }

      System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");

   try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);

        //query users
        Java2MySql j = new Java2MySql();
        j.getUsers(conn);
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
       try {
            conn.close();
          } catch (Throwable ignore){}

     }
 }

 private void getUsers(Connection conn){

 Statement stmt = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;
  try{
      stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
      String query = "select * from users ;" ;

      s = stmt.executeQuery(query) ;

       while ( rs.next() ) {
           int numColumns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
           for ( int i = 1 ; i <= numColumns ; i++ ) {
                   System.out.println( "COLUMN " + i + " = " + rs.getObject(i) );
              }
         }

    }catch(SQLException ex){
      // handle any errors
      System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
      System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
    }finally {
             try {
                  rs.close();
                 } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {}

            try{
                 stmt.close();
               } catch(SQLException sqlEx){}
             }
         }

  }
```

Exception:

```
$java Java2MySql
Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?
MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myBlog
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at Java2MySql.main(Java2MySql.java:22)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `install the jar manually` is it part of your CLASSPATH?

Comment: check if driver is in classpath.

Comment: I tried javac -cp /home/ec2-user/development Java2MySql.java , the jar file is in the location specified there, still getting the error though.

Comment: Not related though `s = stmt.executeQuery(query) ;` shouldn't be `rs = stmt.executeQuery(query) ;` Also add `e.printStackTrace();` in every `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

The JAR in question needs to be in your CLASSPATH. You may wish to set its locations explicitly before the Java app you're attempting to run using the -classpath parameter when calling `java` or set the CLASSPATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is why dont you specify the database in the url itself. 
secondly remove semicolon that is at the end of the query which is inside the double quotes.
Third thing is make 
`rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);`
finally have the mysql-connector.jar in your classpath.